# Bring 2d array contents into 1d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to recreate the Thue Morse sequence in Java console and need to bring the contents of a 1 dimensional array into a 2 dimensional one. I tried using 2 for loops, with one nested, but receive the Ljava.lang.String;@42d3bd8b as a result

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String[][] array = new String [x][x];
    String thue   = "0";
    String morse  = "1";


    //
    for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
        String t = thue;             // save away values
        String m = morse;
        thue  += m;
        morse += t;

    }

    String[] split = (thue.split("(?!^)"));

    for (var y = 0; y<split.length; y++){
        if (split[y] == "0"){
            split[y] = "+";
        }
        else split[y] = "-";
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length;j++){
            array[i][j] = (split[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }



}
```

Comment: What do you expect when you write
thue.split("(?!^)") ?
Your algorithm is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 corrections to be made

1)in this code

```
   if (split[y] == "0"){
        split[y] = "+";
    }
```

Strings cannot be compared as primitives. Replace [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) operator with equals method as such

```
    if (split[y].equals("0")){
        split[y] = "+";
    }
```

2)Arrays [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method can be used to convert only 1D arrays to string format.

You have to use the [deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) for your purpose

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Comment: We can use "==" for type String in Java.

Comment: True but mostly a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix it, I converted array into a integer array and then later on when setting split[index] equal to the indicies of array, I just added and Intger.parseInt around the split[index]